# Triggering a Jenkins job on a timer from a job run through polling

Tags: jenkins

We currently poll svn and run a job if there are any changes. We then trigger a job if the initial job passes.

Additionally, I'd like to trigger a second job that only runs once a day. So if the initial job (job 1) runs 40 times, job 2 would also run 40 times, but job 3 would only run 1 time. (It can be decoupled as long as job 3 knows exactly what machine the last instance of job 1 ran on)

My initial thought was to use a plugin similar to Node stalker (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Node+Stalker+Plugin) to just get the value of the node the previous run was on. The plugin doesn't appear to be working (it runs on whatever node as if the plugin does nothing).

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of another way to do this in a similar manner to node stalker, however two other options come to mind.

The ugly:
If all the machines have a network drive they can access just keep a text file and when a machine completes job 1 and 2 successfully then it updates that text file with a unique identifier for that name, then Job three reads that file and it knows who ran jobs 1 and 2 last.

The less ugly:
This one depends on how long it takes to run jobs 1 and 2 (shorter is better, longer may not be feasible).  Run a 4 job chain:

> job3 launcher -> job 1 -> job 2 -> job 3.

This way you can track what machine is being used for job 1 and job 2 and pass those along as build variables into job 3.

Comment: I had thought of both of these. The issue becomes one of bloat. Storing a text file isn't a horrible situation, it's just really ugly. Running a three job chain isn't really that big of an issue (it adds approximately a half hour to the total execution time, which is insignificant in this case), but I'd need to make an extra job (which in this case is actually more significant due to the setup- multiple configurations all need their own job).